# how to implement bar chart with differnt colors as show in pic in REACT-NATIVE. help me out of this

Tags: charts, react-native, bar-chart, react-native-ios

how to implement [barchart in react native different colors bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kykj.png)
I tried so many libraries but not giving me accurate results.
not getting proper example to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with svg API use [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg)

You can fully implement Text, Rectangle with various options.